# Add functions to image buttons in react

Tags: reactjs, function, anchor, google-signin, facebook-login

I have the code for a facebook and a google button on my react app but I don't want to use the standerd lock but I have my styled buttons as image assets and don't know how to put the functionality inside the image.

I tried anchor tag with onClick but and I get no errors but when I click nothing happens.

here is the Facebook signin component (facebooklogin.js) code:

```
import React from "react";
import {LoginSocialFacebook} from "reactjs-social-login";
import {FacebookLoginButton} from "react-social-login-buttons";
import  {useState} from 'react';

function FacebookLogin()   {      
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);
    return(
        <div>
        {!profile ? <LoginSocialFacebook
      appId="922883705581488"
      onResolve={(response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setProfile(response.data);
      }}
      onReject={(error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }}
      >
        <FacebookLoginButton />
      </LoginSocialFacebook>: ''}
  
      {profile ? 
        <div>
          <h1>{profile.name}</h1>
          <img src={profile.picture.data.url} />
        </div> : 
      ''}
      </div>
    );
}
export default FacebookLogin
```

and here is the google sign in component (GoogleLogin.js):

```
import React from "react"; 
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

function GoogleLogin () {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    console.log(" Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
    var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(userObject);
    setUser(userObject);
    document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden =true;
  }

   function handleSignOut(event) {
     setUser({});
     document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden =false;
   }

  useEffect(()   => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "246695638318- 
    n1css7uk54ali3qj59rc9cijrkrciigi.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    callback: handleCallbackResponse
   });

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
   document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
   {theme: "outline", size: "large"}
  );

  google.accounts.id.prompt();

  }, []);

  // If we have no user: sign in button
  // if we have a user: show the log out button
 return (
     <div>
      <div id="signInDiv"></div>
       { Object.keys(user).length !== 0 && 
        <button onClick={(e) => handleSignOut(e)}>Sign Out</button>
       }
      { user && 
       <div>
        <img src={user.picture}></img>
        <h3>{user.name}</h3>
       </div>
      }
      
      
      
      </div>


      
);


}

export default GoogleLogin
```

App.js:

```
import FacebookLogin from "./components/facebooklogin";
import GoogleLogin from "./components/GoogleLogin";
import { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import background from './cover.png'
import  SecondLogin  from "./SecondLogin";
import Google from "./components/GoogleLogin";






class App extends Component { 
    render(){ 
 return (

    <div className="App">
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
backgroundSize: "cover",
width: '1000px', height:'1000px', position: 'relative', left:'-300px'

    }}>
<h1>Welcome to the<h1></h1> W3llbeing Games</h1>
    
<img className="imgf" src= {require('./Loginscreen/Sign_up_fb.png')}  alt=""></img>
<br></br>
<img className="imgg" src= {require('./Loginscreen/Sign_up_google.png')}  alt=""></img>
<br></br>
<img className="imga" src= {require('./Loginscreen/Sign_up_apple.png')}  alt=""></img>
<br></br>
<img className="imge" src= {require('./Loginscreen/Sign_up_email.png')}  alt=""></img>
   <p>Already have an account?<a><u> sign in here</u></a> </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

The script for google login in index.html file:

```
 <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer>. </script>
```

and I want to make the first two img have the functionaliy of the facebook and google login.

Comment: You can customize your button to have an image inside it. The code you are showing is not linked to those images at all.

Comment: try to add a snippet.